# I need to find the next element that is not a sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have following HTML:

```
<span>
    <span id="x1" class="x">X1</span>
</span>
<span>
    <span>
        <span id="x2" class="x">X2</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

And `$(this)` is the `<span id="x1" ...>`.

What is the best way to find next element matching `.x` with jQuery?
The structure of the actual document is unpredictable, so the HTML provided is only an example.

I can't use `nextAll` as it only finds siblings.
If I do `$('.x')`, it finds all, but I'll have to iterate/compare.
Is there a better solution?

See also: http://jsfiddle.net/JZ9VW/1/.

Comment: Define "best". It might be one or more of fastest, most efficient, least code, easy to understand, etc.

Comment: Epik don't forget to review your answers :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that you seem to be unwilling to make assumptions about the structure of the markup, a class-based selector is best. If elements aren't being added/removed then you can select them once and keep them around as an optimization.

```
var exes = $('.x');
var x1 = $('#x1');
var nextEx = exes.eq(exes.index(x1) + 1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/QKawu

With a *truly* unpredictable HTML structure, asking for "the next element" only makes sense in the context of "the collection of elements with the specified class name," which is exactly what the above code reflects.

Comment: One little thing: I'd restrict the query to the closest common ancestor: `var $exes = $( '.x', '#ancestor' );`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas maybe, if only the OP gave me any confidence in predictable HTML structure. No such confidence was instilled.

Answer (score 1):

Find the parent, then get the parent's next sibling, then find the class.

`.parent().next().find('.x')`

Comment: "*The structure of the actual document is unpredictable, so the HTML provided is only an example.*"